# Bluescreen after changing SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, bsod

I've upgraded my laptop by putting a M.2 SSD in it. After installing the OS on it, and some other programs bluescreens started to emerge. In the first 2 weeks or so it was working fine but after that period not a single day passes without receiving at least one bluescreen. It might be a windows problem but idk.

If someone could help me with this, it would be awesome!

Comment: I really recommend to make a backup. :-) As there are missing information in your question, it's pretty hard to help you out. Please let us know more details: - What type is the new SSD? - What OS are you using? - What's the error on the bluescreen? Possible solutions: - Did you try to repair the OS? - Did you try to update the Firmwarte of the SSD? Maybe also BIOS etc. - Try to check the SSD with a Live LINUX CD (first backup the SSD as you have to recover it after that).

Comment: Please post several crash dumps `.dmp` files from the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump`.

Comment: - NVMe SSD
- Windows 10
- I can't find the picture with the error, for now i'm waiting for it do it's job
- I've tried to repair the OS but i didn't tried to update the firmware, but the bios is up to date

Comment: Here is what i found in that folder

https://we.tl/t-n52HXKjbmV

Comment: ADATA XPG NVMe SSD

Answer (score 1):

The examination of your crash dumps shows that they are caused by the driver
`FocusriteUSBSwRoot.sys`. I would therefore think that you have a Focusrite
device connected to the computer via USB.

Crashes caused by Focusrite seem to be frequent. The following is what users
have done trying to solve them, although only the first point seems to have helped:

- [Turn Off USB Selective Suspend Setting in Power Options](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/73187-turn-off-usb-selective-suspend-windows-10-a.html)
- Download the driver for the device from the [Focusrite website](https://focusrite.com/)
- Contact Focusrite Support.

Comment: Thank you very much mate!